# How do you add two (or more) projects in one solution to git in Visual Studio separately?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I had one project -> I added it to git (so Visual Studio tracks the changes and I can commit throught it etc.) -> then I created a second project in the same solution -> I can't add it to git.

Visual Studio is still "bound" to the first project and doesn't show an option to add the second project to git too.

How do I add both of those projects to git? I could have added to git the whole solution, but now it's too late and I want to have them separately anyways. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4sfw.png)

Comment: git doesn't know, nor care, about Visual Studio. Your problem is likely that you created the second project outside of the repository. P.S.: Try closing and reopening the solution, looks like a UI issue in VS to me.

Comment: Yeah, that's why the question is not about git, but about git integration in Visual Studio. That's what I'm having problems with. I could have added it to git using... Well, git; but I want the Visual Studio integration.